# How to close modal when user clicks anywhere outside of the modal when there are multiple modal at the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using modal example from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2)
 for the two buttons at the same page and each of them opens different modal.

Problem is that function that controls close of modal when user clicks outside of it working only for one modal but not for the second one.

I tried a lot of options, but seems that non of them are working.

I tried to add **OR** statement for **if** condition, but without any results :

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if ((event.target == modal) || (event.target == modall)) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

also I tried to write separate function to every modal:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modall) {
        modall.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

May you know where I am missing the point?

Many thanks for all help, looking forward.

Comment: Since you have two modal, then you also need at least two of that, one for each `ID` of the modal

Comment: Your question is same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624453/cant-use-multiple-modal-popup/43624524#43624524)

Comment: Can you actually show your code that isn't working, all you have given us is a link to code that is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be straightforward, but it works in my case.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById("myModal1");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal2");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close second")[0];


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
  <button id="myBtn1" class="btn" type="button">Modal 1</button>  
  <button id="myBtn2" class="btn" type="button">Modal 2</button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close second">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Node.contains` can fulfill your goal, here is an excerpt from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

> The Node.contains() method returns a Boolean value indicating whether
>   a node is a descendant of a given node or not.
>
> Syntax node.contains( otherNode )

I've enclosed an example to demonstrate how it works in practice

```js
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('modal-1');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('modal-2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("modal-1-button");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("modal-2-button");


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}
btn2.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}



// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

window.onclick = function (event) {
  var modal1 = document.getElementById("modal-1");
  var modal2 = document.getElementById("modal-2");
  if (modal1.style.display === "block") {
    var modal1Content = modal1.querySelector(".modal-content");
    if (!modal1Content.contains(event.target)) {
      modal1.style.display = "none";
    }    
  }
  if (modal2.style.display === "block") {
    var modal2Content = modal1.querySelector(".modal-content");
    if (!modal2Content.contains(event.target)) {
      modal2.style.display = "none";
    }    
  }
};
```

```css
#modal-1 {
  
  background-color: green;
}

#modal-2 {
 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="modal-1-button">Modal - 1</button>
<button id="modal-2-button">Modal - 2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">     
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="modal-2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">     
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: X button do not work on Modal - 1. You might take a look at the provided answer.

Comment: Just ignore it since it has no functionality at all, you can simply remove it in html. Your question was *`user clicks anywhere outside of the modal`* so I followed your requirement

Comment: I have updated my answer with removing x icon, that's not a main point in your question but I removed it anyway